# How to save a highScore on libGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, save

I want to save a highScore in my game made with libGDX.

I tried to use this tutorial :
http://niklasnson.com/programming/network/tips%20and%20tricks/2017/09/15/libgdx-save-and-load-game-data.html

There is my code :

GameData.class :

```java
public class GameData {

    private static double highScore;

    public static double getHighScore() {
        return highScore;
    }

    public static void setHighScore(double hs) {
        highScore = hs;
    }
}
```

PlayState.class :

```java
    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
[...]
        if(GameData.getHighScore() < score) {
            GameData.setHighScore(score);

        }
[...]
        sb.end();
    }
```

MenuState.class :

```java
public class MenuState extends State {
    private BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
    private String HS = String.valueOf(GameData.getHighScore());
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.begin();
        [...]
        font.draw(sb, "Score : " + HS, 20, 400);
        sb.end();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my highscore is reset each time a start a new game.
Where is my mistake ? I hope my question is not too stupid and I not forget something in my code here. Please forgive me in that case.

Thank you very much in advance.
Best regards,
Tenecifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never saving the highscore, you just store it inside of a variable.
You are using a static variable but these are not saved after restarting your program.

I think LibGDX Preferences is that what you're searching for.

You can read about it [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) in their wiki.

Update your setHighscoreMethod:
First put in this line:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
```

After that you can start storing your highscore, e.g.:

```
prefs.putInteger("highscore", 10);
```

After editing make sure to save:

```
prefs.flush();
```

You will also have to update the getHighscore method.
To read the saved highscore just call:

```
prefs.getInteger("highscore", 0);
```

Then 0 is the value that should be returned when no highscore is saved yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not persisting `highScore` anywhere outside of your application instance context. Such `private` field as in your `GameData` will be destroyed as soon as you will close the game. Think about Word document window on your PC and what will happen if you will suddenly turn off your computer - it will dissapear, with the content, after reboot unless you will *save it to the HDD*

To save object to the persistent memory in LibGDX you can use [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences)

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");

// Persist some value 
prefs.putString("name", "Donald Duck");
prefs.flush();

// And load it after application restart (or event without restart)
String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name stored"); // 'No name stored' is default value in case such key does not exist
```

You can also implement some *cloud* service to keep your game state (and even share it between devices) like [Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) from Google Services or [App42 API](http://api.shephertz.com/) from Shephertz (creators od AppWarp)